# Desilylation with potassium fluoride and methanol

Tags: organic-chemistry

Recently, I have done following reaction with KF adn methanol:

[image]

I don't understand why the sp-carbon silicon bond breaks and why no other sp3 carbon silicon bond breaks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is more stable: $\ce{RC#C^-}$ or $\ce{H3C^-}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Desilylation mechanism with fluoride](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/132012/desilylation-mechanism-with-fluoride) pay particualr attention to the last paragraph

Comment: So the sp carbon-silicon bond breaks because it forms a more stable anion than the other sp3 carbons?

Comment: That is exactly it.